# Maximisation problem

Tags: inequality, optimization

I am trying the following question:

> If$$a+b+c+d=0,\;a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=1$$ Then what is the maximum value of
>   $ab+bc+cd+da?$

By the rearrangement inequality I can get $ab+bc+cd+da\leq 1$ but I am having trouble bringing the first condition into this. I have tried squaring it but that does not look like it leads anywhere. By playing with some numbers it looks like the answer might be $-½$. Help?

Comment: a² + b² + c² + d² + 2ab + 2cd + 2ac + 2bc + 2ad + 2bd =0 then your result follows. I squared (a+b+c+d).

Comment: @AtulGangwar That doesn't work, you get extra terms by squaring (there is no $bd$ or $ac$ term in what I am trying to maximise)

Comment: It might help you that what you are trying to maximize is $(a+c)(b+d)=-(a+c)^2$

Comment: I got to: $2(a+c)(b+d) = -(a+c)^2 - (b+d)^2$. Not sure how you continued that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ab+bc+cd+da = (a+c)(b+d) = -(a+c)^2 \leq 0$, and $\text{max} = 0$ when $a = -c$,
and so $b = -d$. Thus $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 = 2(a^2+b^2) = 1 \to a^2+b^2 = \dfrac{1}{2}$